# Rows to columns in MySQL with boolean values

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

I am trying to build an SQL statement (for MySQL) to solve the following problem:

I have a table **transport_table** with the information from which location there are transports to which other location. This table is ordered by transport_from (ascending), and then by transport_to (ascending). It is possible that some locations only receive good, others only send goods, most locations, however, send and receive goods. It is also possible to send goods to the own location.

```
---------------------------------
| transport_from | transport_to |
-----------------+---------------
| 1              | 2            |
-----------------+---------------
| 1              | 3            |
-----------------+---------------
| 1              | 7            |
-----------------+---------------
| 3              | 3            |
-----------------+---------------
| 3              | 5            |
-----------------+---------------
| 4              | 5            |
-----------------+---------------
| 4              | 6            |
-----------------+---------------
| 4              | 7            |
-----------------+---------------
| 5              | 3            |
-----------------+---------------
| 7              | 1            |
-----------------+---------------
| 7              | 6            |
---------------------------------
```

But I need the table in another format, and it would be great if this could be achieved by MySQL (if this is not possible, I could still use a real programming language). Can you help me how to get to a table indicating with boolean values if there was a transport between the two locations. to achieve this, I need to transfer the rows to the columns, and to set the boolean values if a specific row exists in the original table. But I have no idea how to achieve this.
Such a table should look like this:

```
----------------------------------
| id | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
-----+---+---+---+---+---+---+----
|  1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
-----+---+---+---+---+---+---+----
|  2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
-----+---+---+---+---+---+---+----
|  3 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
-----+---+---+---+---+---+---+----
|  4 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
-----+---+---+---+---+---+---+----
|  5 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
-----+---+---+---+---+---+---+----
|  6 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
-----+---+---+---+---+---+---+----
|  7 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
----------------------------------
```

It would be great if you helped me with this problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that rows represent `TRANSPORT_FROM` and columns represent `TRANSPORT_TO`(because that seems to be what you meant), try:

```
SELECT A.TRANSPORT_FROM,
MAX(CASE WHEN TRANSPORT_TO = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TO_1,
MAX(CASE WHEN TRANSPORT_TO = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TO_2,
MAX(CASE WHEN TRANSPORT_TO = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TO_3,
MAX(CASE WHEN TRANSPORT_TO = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TO_4,
MAX(CASE WHEN TRANSPORT_TO = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TO_5,
MAX(CASE WHEN TRANSPORT_TO = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TO_6,
MAX(CASE WHEN TRANSPORT_TO = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TO_7
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT TRANSPORT_FROM FROM TRANSPORT_TABLE UNION SELECT DISTINCT TRANSPORT_TO FROM TRANSPORT_TABLE) A
LEFT JOIN
TRANSPORT_TABLE B
ON A.TRANSPORT_FROM = B.TRANSPORT_FROM
GROUP BY A.TRANSPORT_FROM;
```

I have done a UNION in an inner query to fill for the missing IDs(2 and 6) for the `TRANSPORT_FROM`. You could also do this by creating a dummy table containing all `TRANSPORT_FROM` IDs and using that table in place of that inner query represented by the alias `A`.

**EDIT** To make it dynamic.
I am not sure if this will work but I have tried a version that should at least give a direction.

```
SELECT
GROUP_CONCAT(
    CONCAT(
    ' MAX(CASE WHEN TRANSPORT_TO = ',
    t.TRANSPORT_TO,
    ' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TO_',
    t.TRANSPORT_TO
    )
) INTO @PivotQuery
FROM
(SELECT TRANSPORT_TO FROM TRANSPORT_TABLE GROUP BY TRANSPORT_TO) t;

SET @PivotQuery = CONCAT('SELECT TRANSPORT_FROM,', @PivotQuery, ' FROM TRANSPORT_TABLE GROUP BY TRANSPORT_FROM ORDER BY TRANSPORT_FROM');


PREPARE statement FROM @PivotQuery;
EXECUTE statement;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE statement;
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! Your assumption is right. But there is one major problem: There are 500 locations, and I would not like to hardcode them, but to let the query adapt dynamically (new locations can be added every day, but the SQL query should remain the same). Do you have an idea for this, too? It would not be a problem if the locations that only receive goods are missing in the resulting table. Only the locations that send goods are important.

Comment: The dynamic statement from the edited post gives the following error for PREPARE statement FROM @PivotQuery:
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax near 'FROM TRANSPORT_TABLE GROUP BY TRANSPORT_FROM ORDER BY TRANSPORT_FROM' in row 1

With another dataset (which has the same example values as in my question above; this means: the IDs are without special characters) I do not get this error, but another error:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getClauses() on null in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\vendor\phpmyadmin\sql-parser\src\Utils\Query.php:567 Stack tr[...]

Any ideas?